# Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I have this error on IIS but on localhost site work's good.

Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.

Stack Trace:

```
[BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.]
   System.Reflection.Assembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection) +0
   System.Reflection.Assembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection) +43
   System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +127
   System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +142
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +28
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +46

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.]
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +613
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +203
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) +105
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +178
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler..ctor(VirtualPath configPath, Boolean supportLocalization, String outputAssemblyName) +54
   System.Web.Compilation.ApplicationBuildProvider.GetGlobalAsaxBuildResult(Boolean isPrecompiledApp) +232
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileGlobalAsax() +52
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled() +337

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.]
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ReportTopLevelCompilationException() +58
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled() +512
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters) +729

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +8894031
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +85
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +333
```

Please help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check IISPool for the website and make it to use the latest version of .Net. This will resolve your problem.

See snaps below!

[image]

Comment: @user1545035 - Then mark it as the answer ! Jigar has given the answer which has helped u

Comment: Although this *might* solve the problem, it does not answer WHY this exception is thrown. I have a similar case but none of the references assemblies uses the EntityFramework, so why on earth is this exception thrown? It makes no sense - unless the entire IIS team have made dependencies to favor the use of .NET Framework 4, which then again opens up for other strange behaviors - such as requiring a reference to Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll although no MCV is being used. This is just slobbish work from the IIS team. Period.